# WHy is my DNS zone gone?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, ns-record

I changed my name servers for the domain mmaiato.com from the default GoDaddy name servers to custom NS records as part of my web hosting requirements.

I did not ask for a change of registrar. I did not ask for a change of SOA.
Why cant I manage my DNS zone at GoDaddy after changing NS records?

Comment: Please be more clear about exactly what change you made, and ideally why. I can see that GoDaddy is your registrar, but you have changed your name servers to EPIZY.COM, so you need to manage your DNS records with whoever EPIZY.COM is.

Answer (score 2):

> I changed my name servers for the domain mmaiato.com from the default GoDaddy name servers to custom NS records

and

> Why cant I manage my DNS zone at GoDaddy after changing NS records?

Are mutually exclusive. As you changed things so that "Provider1" is not your DNS provider anymore then you shouldn't expect to be able to continue acting on your zone content at that provider, and you need to do your changes through "Provider2" UI and/or API.

Each domain has, at any given time, one active DNS provider and zone content changes have to happen at that provider, nowhere else. If unsure about DNS you might want to ask help from your DNS provider(s) and/or registrar.

Answer (score 1):

Because your NS record defines who is the authoritative DNS. If I'm reading this correctly, at the moment anyone looking for your DNS records is told to go to `ns2.epizy.com`, and so it is the DNS zone at epizy.com which you have to edit.